# SharedPreferences not persisting through Android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have an `IntroActivity` where I'm saving a value that's saved from an EditText, in a shared pref.

In my `SettingsActivity` I try to edit that value, but even when I call the shared preferences value with the key I just edited, it still shows the old value. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the `IntroActivity`

```
public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

    String PREF = "MyPrefs";
    Button mDone;
    EditText mTemperature;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        mDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        mTemperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temperature);

        mDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int temperature = Integer.parseInt(mTemperature.getText().toString());
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                edit.putInt("sweater", temperature);
                edit.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the `SettingsActivity`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button mDone;
    EditText mTemperature;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        mTemperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temperature);

        mDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sweater", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();

                int temp = preferences.getInt("sweater", 0);
                int updateSweater = Integer.parseInt(mTemperature.getText().toString());
                edit.remove("sweater");
                edit.putInt("sweater", updateSweater);
                boolean saved = edit.commit();
                preferences.getInt("sweater", 0);

                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Sweater Weather Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Map<String, ?> map = preferences.getAll();
                for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : map.entrySet()){
                    Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " +
                            entry.getValue().toString());
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to edit that value, but even when I call the shared preferences
>   value with the key I just edited, it still shows the old value. What
>   am I doing wrong?

Because `SharedPreferences` name is different in both Activities.

In `IntroActivity` using `MyPrefs` and in `SettingsActivity` using `sweater`.

Use same name  in both Activities. to get it work  change `sweater` to `MyPrefs` in  `SettingsActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

These two line are different in both activities

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sweater", 0);
```

For this problem you have to create two pref files and read the values from another file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in your SettingsActivity, you need to use 
`SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);`

Instead of `SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sweater", 0);`

You are storing the value in "sweater" Preference and loading it from "MyPrefs".